# Distinct Grouping on Large table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a decently large table (~20 million) with a primary key column and another column with large text strings (~ 250 char). The primary key column is all unique but the text strings have repeats. I want to remove all redundant text strings and “distinctify” the table  or create a new table to the same affect.
I want to leave only rows with distinct text strings. I don’t care which of the several primary keys with each url are thrown away. Even running a select distinct on only the string column results in memory overflow. What other options are there?

Comment: You can try a `group by` instead . . . and then try an index on the colum . . . otherwise, I think you might need a staged process of some sort.

Comment: Do you have any idea what proportion of the table are duplicates?

Comment: @MartinSmith Im not sure but it's more than half

Comment: Really a select distinct on the other columns results in memory overflow?  Please post the actual message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory overflow is likely due to returning such a large resulset back to SSMS. If you `Select min(ID), TextColumn Into TableXYZ Group By TextColumn`, you should get around this issue. Once the 'Distinctified' results are in a separate table, you can then go about deleting/archiving the records in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

At one level this is the same question as that asked in [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/73226).

You could use [the `ROW_NUMBER` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822833/73226) but this will require sorting the 20 million rows. Or [the `GROUP BY` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/73226) which may be less memory demanding if it uses a hash aggregate.

Another more offbeat approach that might be considered here, as you are anticipating less than 50% of the table will be retained, would be to create a new table as below

```
CREATE TABLE Deduped
(
Id INT,
CharColumn VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
)
```

and insert all rows into it

```
DECLARE @I INT = 2000000000;
INSERT INTO Deduped
SELECT TOP(@I) Id, CharColumn
FROM   OriginalTable
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@I = 0))
```

This may well avoid any memory consuming operators at all as duplicates are discarded using the B tree being created.

Answer (score 1):

```
select column1_primary, column2_text, count(*) from table group by column2_text, column1_primary   having count(*) > 1
```

After this you will get records containing duplicate text then you can run:

```
Delete from table where column2_primary in(select column1_primary, count(*) from table group by column2_text, column1_primary   having count(*) > 1)
```

This will remove all the duplicate text from your table and the left behind table will consist of unique strings or you can use insert select to insert rows in new table.

I have tested this on a 7 million records table and it takes around 1 minutes to select the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Better than finding and deleting could be inserting into a new table. You could directly SELECT your distinct result into a new table. If something like COUNT() OVER or GROUP BY won't work, you still could use a CURSOR and do this one by one. Use an unique key and BEGIN TRY...CATCH.